# iPad scaling issue

Tags: html, ipad

My website is built using HTML5 Boilerplate, and is being cropped on the iPad when the iPad is positioned vertically, but appears the way it's supposed to when the iPad is horizontal. Here's the link to the site I built: http://designedbyallison.com/hhsc/

Basically, the area that shows the website is being scaled down while the website design elements themselves appear to be the right size within the iPad display area.

I've tried to locate which lines of code in the CSS or JavaScript files control this aspect of the website but can't figure it out. I have even tried removing the JavaScript and CSS within the html file and the scaling issue is still apparent. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the [<meta name="viewport" />](http://www.html-5.com/metatags/index.html#viewport-meta-tag) tag helpful.

I'd start with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
```